# How can I set the percentage width of a text box in a singular column grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store

Is there any way I can set the percentage width of a text box in a singular column grid other then the hack I created below? As this solution seems messy as I need to set two columns, one for the control one for the remaining space.

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray" Text="Hello world" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. This is the only way to ensure your TextBox is 80% of the width of the containing column.